# Remembering if javascript was run before and not running it again if it was [EnjoyHint.js]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using EnjoyHint.js on my website (its basically for website walkthroughs/tours). The .js file which initialises the tour runs each time I reload the page. This means the tour keeps appearing even if you have seen it already when reloading the page or visiting it a second time. I am unsure of how to stop this from happening. I only want the .js script to run once and not run again if the user reloads or visits the page again.

Is it possible to remember if the .js file was run on the computer before and not run it again if it was. If someone visits the website, I don't want the website tour to keep appearing if they have already seen it once before.

Thanks!

Comment: What about Cookies? :)

Comment: Can you put the final code so I can check it please? I am trying to use this but I don't know where to put the answer's code. I tried in the onStart of the new EnjoyHint but it does not work if I don't call enjoyhint_instance.run(); outside of the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cookies is common for this kind of task. There are [plenty of libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+cookie+library) to use them in an easy way, but for this, you don't really need one:

```
// If the cookie is not set to 1
if(document.cookie.indexOf('tourIsDone=1') < 0){
    //Launch the tour
    launchTour();
    // Set the cookie (you can also do it once the tour is finished)
    document.cookie = "tourIsDone=1";
}
```

**Explanation, since `document.cookie` can be confusing**

When reading `document.cookie`, you get a long String containing every cookie :

```
cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2
```

Checking for `document.cookie.indexOf(nameOfCookie) < 0` will make sure it's not in there.

However, in order to set a single cookie without changing the others, you just need to do:

```
document.cookie = "newCookie=newValue";
```

Comment: Hey, forgive me if I am understanding wrong. So I initially create a cookie and set the value to 0: `document.cookie = "tourIsDone=0";` then I do your if statement to check if the cookie is set value 0. If it is then it launches the tour and sets the value of the cookie to 1. What does `indexOf` do?

Comment: @Tahmid Don't initialize it to 0, because if it was previously set to 1, it will reset it and launch the tour every time. The code I put in my answer is all you need. Doing `document.cookie = "tourIsDone=0";` would only be useful if you wanted the browser to "forget" that the tour was ever done (good for testing). [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/String/indexOf) looks for a String within another String. If it finds it, it returns its index. If it does not, it returns `-1` which is less than 0 (Hence the `if` condition `indexOf(...) < 0`)

Comment: I see, I've copied your code and for some reason it doesn't work, it still shows the tour when page is reloaded. I've replaced `launchTour();` with `enjoyhint_instance.run();`

Comment: It should work ([Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/0bs8s5xf/)). Are you doing this on a server? If that is the case and it still doesn't work, paste your code in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) so I can have a look at it.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I was testing it locally which is why it wasn't working (took me long enough to figure out!) but it works fine when I pushed it to the server! Again, thank you for the help, it is much much appreciated. Learnt something new today :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked! I forgot to mention that some browsers don't accept cookies when working locally...

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)
  Harder to use, works everywhere.
- [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
  Easier to use, might not work on very old browsers. Compatability sheet [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).